# How to make a link appear when specific actions are taken?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm not quite sure how to ask this question, so I'm just going to give an example of what I'm looking for..

Let's say I have a product that is selling for $5.
I want to give visitors an opportunity to pick this product up for free.
All they have to do is click ANY of the 3 social buttons (facebook, twitter, G+, all that good stuff), then the link for their free download would appear.

My problem is, I have NO idea what to search for to find something like this. Whether it be a pre-built script or a paid software (preferably on the cheaper side).

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not as trivial as it sounds depending on the social buttons as I know for a fact the Google+ `+1` buttons are an iframe and therefore you cannot detect whether the user has clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You could created a div on the page below the twitter buttons with the link in it.

```
<div id="freedownload" style="display:none;">LINK TO DOWNLOAD</div>
```

Then use jquery to show the div when the buttons are clicked.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".social_media_button_class",function() {
        $( "#freedownload" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Just make sure you replace the div ID's or classes similar to whatever you're using on your site. Also include the jquery library.

http://jquery.com/

Comment: This is not a bad answer as long as you wrap the media buttons in the class as mentioned you'll be able to count the number of clicks but not necessarily know which one was clicked. If that doesn't matter a solution of this sort with a `clickCounter` will work.

Comment: Okay, so if I were to have 4 different social media buttons, I would just assign each of them with the class 'social_media_button'. And then when any 1 of those 4 buttons are clicked, #freedownload would pop up.. Right?